# Is there a way to modify decorators option at build time?

Tags: angular, typescript, tsc, typescript-compiler-api

I have an Angular standard application and I want switch some components at build time. 
I want change, with one ast trasformer, the @Component decorator options like this:

- login.component.ts

@Component({ selector: 'login' .... })

into

@Component({ selector: 'not-use-this-login' .... })

- custom-login.component.ts

@Component({ selector: 'custom-login' .... })

into

@Component({ selector: 'login' .... })

If I can modify the ts files before Angular build process I suppose Angular will render the custom-login.component.ts and not the standard one.
This can be very useful because I can compile the application for many customers and not change the standard code.
I read Angular build code and they do something really similar with template option for inject inline html.
I've created a github repo for test this trick: 
https://github.com/gioboa/ng-ts-transformer
@angular-builders/custom-webpack allow you to define an extra webpack config. By ts-loader I call my transformer (transformer.js file).
I try many ways to replace the selector, but unfortunately without success. ast API documentation in very poor.

Comment: check the links of Netanel basal https://netbasal.com/inspiration-for-custom-decorators-in-angular-95aeb87f072c

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Custom decorators are evaluated at runtime, when class is created, and It's too late for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is using only the compiler api as I'm not that familiar with angular or the build process, but will hopefully be of some help and you should be able to adapt it.

1. Find the component decorators that match what you're looking for.
2. Transform the string literals you want to change within the decorator's call expression's first argument's object literal's property that is a property assignment with the name "selector"'s initializer.

Using my tool [ts-ast-viewer.com](https://ts-ast-viewer.com/) helps to see what you need to be checking for...

```
// Note: This code mixes together the act of analyzing and transforming.
// You may want a stricter separation, but that requires creating an entire
// architecture around this.

import * as ts from "typescript";

// create a source file ast
const sourceFile = ts.createSourceFile("/file.ts", `import { Component } from 'whereever';

@Component({ selector: 'login' })
class Test {
}
`, ts.ScriptTarget.Latest);

// transform it
const transformerFactory: ts.TransformerFactory<ts.SourceFile> = context => {
    return file => visitChangingDecorators(file, context) as ts.SourceFile;
};
const transformationResult = ts.transform(sourceFile, [transformerFactory]);
const transformedSourceFile = transformationResult.transformed[0];

// see the result by printing it
console.log(ts.createPrinter().printFile(transformedSourceFile));

function visitChangingDecorators(node: ts.Node, context: ts.TransformationContext) {
    // visit all the nodes, changing any component decorators
    if (ts.isDecorator(node) && isComponentDecorator(node))
        return handleComponentDecorator(node);
    else {
        return ts.visitEachChild(node,
            child => visitChangingDecorators(child, context), context);
    }
}

function handleComponentDecorator(node: ts.Decorator) {
    const expr = node.expression;
    if (!ts.isCallExpression(expr))
        return node;

    const args = expr.arguments;
    if (args.length !== 1)
        return node;

    const arg = args[0];
    if (!ts.isObjectLiteralExpression(arg))
        return node;

    // Using these update functions on the call expression
    // and decorator is kind of useless. A better implementation
    // would only update the string literal that needs to be updated.
    const updatedCallExpr = ts.updateCall(
        expr,
        expr.expression,
        expr.typeArguments,
        [transformObjectLiteral(arg)]
    );

    return ts.updateDecorator(node, updatedCallExpr);

    function transformObjectLiteral(objectLiteral: ts.ObjectLiteralExpression) {
        return ts.updateObjectLiteral(objectLiteral, objectLiteral.properties.map(prop => {
            if (!ts.isPropertyAssignment(prop))
                return prop;

            if (!prop.name || !ts.isIdentifier(prop.name))
                return prop;

            if (prop.name.escapedText !== "selector")
                return prop;

            if (!ts.isStringLiteral(prop.initializer))
                return prop;

            if (prop.initializer.text === "login") {
                return ts.updatePropertyAssignment(
                    prop,
                    prop.name,
                    ts.createStringLiteral("not-use-this-login")
                );
            }

            return prop;
        }));
    }
}

function isComponentDecorator(node: ts.Decorator) {
    // You will probably want something more sophisticated
    // that analyzes the import declarations or possibly uses
    // the type checker in an initial pass of the source files
    // before transforming. This naively just checks if the
    // decorator is a call expression and if its expression
    // has the text "Component". This definitely won't work
    // in every scenario and might possibly get false positives.
    const expr = node.expression;
    if (!ts.isCallExpression(expr))
        return false;

    if (!ts.isIdentifier(expr.expression))
        return false;

    return expr.expression.escapedText === "Component";
}
```

Outputs:

```
import { Component } from "whereever";
@Component({ selector: "not-use-this-login" })
class Test {
}
```

Comment: I've implemented the solution in the Angular build, but seems that updatePropertyAssignment create another stringLiteral and don't replace the previous one. In the node now I have 2 selector: 'login' and 'not-use-this-login' maybe I miss something.

Comment: It works in this example. Perhaps post some code in the question that shows the problem happening?

Comment: By using util ( var util = require('util'); ) I finally understand the node object. You are right the code is correct. I see two selector object because one is wrapped into original: object. Anyway Angular compiler doesn't care about my modification. I will study Angular code for better understand what's append. Thanks for your support.